# Запись видео android

Tags: java, android, видео

Добрый день.

Возникла необходимость создать что-то на подобии видеорегистратора, т.е. на экране 2 кнопки - старт и стоп. При нажатии на старт приложение должно производить видеозапись (без превью) отрезками по 2 минуты и сохранять их в папку на sd-карте.

Так вот, столкнулся с проблемой плавного перехода между записанными отрезками. Нужно чтобы конец одного отрезка видео и начала следующего были почти без разрыва. сейчас разрыв около 2-3 сек. Есть ли возможность как-то сократить это?

Запись идет в сервисе, вот его код:

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private static Camera mServiceCamera;
private boolean mRecordingStatus;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
private Boolean isDestroy = false;
private int VIDEO_DURATION = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    //mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
    mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
    mSurfaceHolder = MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("detail", MODE_PRIVATE);
    VIDEO_DURATION = sharedPreferences.getInt("duration", 1);

    super.onCreate();
    if (!mRecordingStatus) {
        startRecording();
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    isDestroy = true;

    stopRecording();

    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;

    super.onDestroy();
}

public boolean startRecording() {

    try {

        //mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Camera.Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width
                + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.unlock();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(this).toString());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "Recording Started");


        mRecordingStatus = true;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isDestroy) {
                    stopRecording();
                    startRecording();
                }
            }
        }, VIDEO_DURATION * 60 * 1000);

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    if (mRecordingStatus) {
        mRecordingStatus = false;
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Recording Stopped");
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
        mMediaRecorder.release();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После проведения тестов выяснилось, что на средних устройствах (Xperia M2 Dual Android 5.1) задержка при переключении - 0.3 - 0.6 сек, а на устройствах чуть ниже среднего (Samsung SM-G313H Android 4.4.2) - 0.6 - 1.1 сек. Для меня вполне допустимо.

Также изменил механизм запуска записи следующего видеоотрезка :

```
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(sharedPreferences.getInt(Constants.DURATION, Constants.DEFAULT_DURATION) * 60 * 1000);
mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
            stopRecording();
            startRecording();
        }
    }
});
```